# Convert a .csv export file to excel, formatting multiple sheets, with filtered and styled tables using Python, stuck on filter/style application

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, pandasgui

PROBLEM: script does not translate into excel format properly, excel rejects filters and table formatting.

Long explanation the bot didn't like:
So i have a .csv file that has a bunch of data in it that i do not need. I have to pull this report daily, format into several tables and filter several columns to create several tables and send it out for work. I wrote this program that allows you to select the .csv file, convert to xlxs, creates 4 sheets, with 4 tables, it gives each sheet a name, creates the header, removes several uneeded columns, and converts each sheets data into a table, also, sheet 1 is hidden on purpose, filters a few columns on each sheet in a different manner, and gives each sheet its own theme..

Get no errors from terminal or debug. It Creates the file.

Get this error from Excel as it forces a repair on the sheet.

Removed Feature: AutoFilter from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)

Removed Feature: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)

Removed Feature: AutoFilter from /xl/tables/table2.xml part (Table)

Removed Feature: Table from /xl/tables/table2.xml part (Table)

Removed Feature: AutoFilter from /xl/tables/table3.xml part (Table)

Removed Feature: Table from /xl/tables/table3.xml part (Table)

[Excel sheet snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d5EP.png)*
*
Here is my wacky code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from pandasgui import show
import pandas as pd
import sys
import openpyxl

class DiscoSnakeGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("The Disco Snake")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.open_button = QPushButton("Open .csv file")
        self.open_button.clicked.connect(self.load_csv)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.open_button)

    def load_csv(self):
        csv_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open CSV", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)")
        if csv_file:
            print(f"CSV file path: {csv_file}")
        self.process_csv(csv_file)

    def process_csv(self, csv_file):
        try:
            with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                start_index = None
                for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                    if line.strip() == 'Devices:':
                        start_index = index + 1
                        break
                df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, skiprows=range(start_index), header=None, engine='python')
        except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
            print(f"Error parsing CSV file: {e}")
            return
       
    
        column_headers = [
            "Server Name", "Device Name", "Make", "Model", "Location", "Logical ID",
            "Device ID", "Camera ID String", "IP Address", "MAC Address", "Firmware Version",
            "Required Firmware Version", "Serial Number", "Connected", "Visible", "Error Flags",
            "Status", "Bitrate", "Resolution", "Quality", "Image Rate", "Encryption",
            "Retention", "Appearance Search:", "Face Recognition:", " "
        ]

        df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

        df.columns = column_headers

        excel_file = "output.xlsx"
        df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)

        columns_to_remove = ['Logical ID', 'Device ID', 'Camera ID String',
                             'Firmware Version', 'Required Firmware Version', 'Error Flags',
                             'Encryption', 'Retention', 'Appearance Search:', 'Face Recognition:']
        df = df.drop(columns=columns_to_remove)

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MASTER', index=False)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='AVIGILON DOWN', index=False)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LEGACY DOWN', index=False)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LEGACY UP', index=False)
        writer.close()

        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
        for sheet in workbook.sheetnames:
            ws = workbook[sheet]
            if sheet == 'MASTER':
                workbook[sheet].sheet_state = 'hidden'
            elif sheet == 'AVIGILON DOWN':
                table = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName="Table1", ref=ws.dimensions)
                style = openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium3")
                table.tableStyleInfo = style
                ws.add_table(table)
                make_column_index = df.columns.get_loc("Make") + 1
                ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(make_column_index, ['Avigilon'])
                connected_column_index = df.columns.get_loc("Connected") + 1
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(connected_column_index, ['FALSE'])
            elif sheet == 'LEGACY DOWN':
                table = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName="Table2", ref=ws.dimensions)
                style = openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium3")
                table.tableStyleInfo = style
                ws.add_table(table)
                make_column_index = df.columns.get_loc("Make") + 1
                ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(make_column_index, [])
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(make_column_index, ['Avigilon'], blank=True)
                connected_column_index = df.columns.get_loc("Connected") + 1
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(connected_column_index, ['FALSE'])
            elif sheet == 'LEGACY UP':
                table = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName="Table3", ref=ws.dimensions)
                style = openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium2")
                table.tableStyleInfo = style
                ws.add_table(table)
                make_column_index = df.columns.get_loc("Make") + 1
                ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(make_column_index, [])
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(make_column_index, ['Avigilon'], blank=True)
                connected_column_index = df.columns.get_loc("Connected") + 1
                ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(connected_column_index, ['TRUE'])

        workbook.save(excel_file)
        
        blank_header_columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed' in col]

        print(blank_header_columns)

        print(f"Excel file saved: {excel_file}")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = DiscoSnakeGUI()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks to whoever solves this puzzle!

Comment: Off topic, but:  You appear to be proficient with pandas, pyqt, etc.  Why bother with the pain of pushing the data back into Excel?  Could you not produce reports directly or make the leap to an interactive dashboard from the data?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm a newb, and have pieced this together from various sources. I am sorry if it is not specific. I'm sure its a matter of just a simple tweak in the code to get it to fall into place.